# Disable past date in FullCalendar for dateClick

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Those who still looking for a solution on how to disable past date click on `Dateclick` event on FullCalendar. can try see solution below, if any of the reader had other idea can post other solution below. It would be much better if there is another easy way. The more solution, the better it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to improve on your string-manipulation of dates, by doing a simple comparison as follows:

```
dateClick: function (info) {
  var clickedDate = getDateWithoutTime(info.date);
  var nowDate = getDateWithoutTime(new Date())
  if (clickedDate >= nowDate) alert("Future date");
  else alert("Past date");
}
```

It is helped by this function:

```
//get date without the time of day
function getDateWithoutTime(dt)
{
  dt.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return dt;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZErwJGx

---

One other option to achieve the same goal is to use the [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) functionality. This lets you dynamically set a start date, before which all dates are disabled:

```
validRange: function (nowDate) {
  return {
    start: nowDate
  };
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwQgWJO

The slight downside of this though is that it also hides any events which occur before the current date - you may not want this.

---

Therefore, another alternative is to use [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) to restrict where the user can select. Note that this relies on you using the `select` callback rather than `dateClick` - but that should not be a big problem.

```
selectAllow: function (info) {
  return (info.start >= getDateWithoutTime(new Date()));
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwQgzZJ

Comment: Oh god this is simple and easiest way, TQ so much for this idea @ADyson. Btw I already read the [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) function, and it not good for me as I also need for past date data on certain situation. It limit my code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is just my current solution to disable past date on FullCalendar. Any idea or improvement would be appreciate to improve the code below.

```
dateClick: function(e) {

    // Get Today
    var dt = calendar.getDate();
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dt.getDate();

    if(month < 9){
        month = '0'+month;
    }

    if(day < 9){    
        day = '0'+day;
    }
    
    var today = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

    // Get Selected Date
    var check = e.dateStr;
                
    let A = today.toString();
    let B = check.toString();

    alert('Date A: ' + A );
    alert('Date B: ' + B );

    if(B >= A){
        alert('Past Date');
    }

    else{
        alert('Future Date');
    }
},
```

Comment: As well as being very long and relying on string manipulation (instead of proper date comparisons), this also produces the wrong result: It outputs "Past date" for future dates, and "Future date" for past dates! Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOZdLWL